# LVM installation on existent Debian9 system

Tags: linux, debian, lvm

I am not very experienced with Linux, and I have to put myself up to date about the below.
We have several old Debian9 systems migrated to Azure. I see no LVM installed on the system, but there is a discussion to start using it for managing the space.

**Question**: Would it be possible to create/map new Physical Volumes to existent partitions (only one partion per disk), without affecting existent data?

The system disks details:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK - no.

The reason is LVM hierarchy of storage is PV->VG->LV. So you need disk to become physical volume, then attach/create volume group and after this create logical volume on which you need to create filesystem. And I am not aware of process of convert partition to LV directly (w/o involving backup)